# How to update multiple rows on table with the result of a select subquery in Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql-update

I have a table "product_quantity_cart" that has a "price" column in Mysql. I want to update all rows that match certain "id" with the result of a select that uses values from two different tables. In order to do so, I am executing a select subquery inside the update and as a result I am getting error 1224: "subquery returns multiple rows". I have read that a subquery like mine is not the right way to achieve what I want in Mysql, so I would like to ask which is the proper way to do it.
My query looks like so:

```
update product_quantity_cart set price_product =
  (
  select quantity*price from (select * from product_quantity_cart) as p_q_c  inner join product 
    on product.id_product=p_q_c.id_product
        where id_shopping_cart=7
        );
'''
As you can see, I intend to update column price_product in all rows from table product_quantity_cart.
```

Comment: Use multiple-table UPDATE syntax, not subquery in SET.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what your tables looks like but I'm just assuming that the `product` in your `inner join product` (given above) is your table2 with columns `p.id_product` and `p.quantity` and your `product_quantity_cart` has columns `id_product`, `price_product`, `c.price`, and `c.id_shopping_cart`

Then the query could be like this;

```
update product_quantity_cart c JOIN product p ON p.id_product = c.id_product
set c.price_product = c.price * p.quantity
WHERE c.id_shopping_cart=7
```

Comment: Worked exacly as I expected. Thank you.